# Python 2to3 tool adds a vowel to my integer

Tags: python, octal, python-2to3

I was running the 2to3 tool on various scripts I'd written to get an idea of what I will need to change to port these to Python 3 (though I will be doing it by hand in the end).

While doing so, I ran into an odd change 2to3 made in one of my scripts:

```
-def open_pipe(pipe, perms=0644):
+def open_pipe(pipe, perms=0o644):
```

**Um...  Why did 2to3 add a "o" in the middle of my "perms" integer?**

That's line 41 from the original source found here:  https://github.com/ksoviero/Public/blob/master/tempus.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try typing `0644` in your python2 shell. It will give you a different number because it is `octal`. In python3, the `0o` signifies an `octal` number.

`python2`:

```
>>> 0644
420
>>>
```

`python3`:

```
>>> 0644
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0644
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o644
420
>>>
```

[New in `python3`](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

> Octal literals are no longer of the form 0720; use 0o720 instead.

Comment: Actually: the `0o` indicates an octal number, because `o644` is considered an identifier not a numeric literal. It might be helpful to mention also `0b` for binary literals and `0x` for hex literals.

Answer (score 3):

According to [What's New In Python 3.0 - Integers](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

> Octal literals are no longer of the form `0720`; use `0o720` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The old notation octal with a single `0` prefix is not allowed anymore in Python 3. To explicitly give an octal value, [you need to prefix the number by a `0o`](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)
>>> 0644
420
>>>

$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 23 2012, 16:48:24)
>>> 0644
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0644
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o644
420
```

According to the documentation, linked above:

> Octal literals are no longer of the form `0720`; use `0o720` instead.

Comment: Actually, you need a prefix of `0o`, not just `o`.