# Smarter Python datetime handling

Tags: python, datetime

Just started coding and I know my code looks less than good.
I am currently building an application where I get weather forecasts via API calls and then print whatever I receive. Thought it could be a good exercise.
One of the parameters is the date for the forecast. The below code does the job, but it feels like I am overcomplicating it a lot.
What I want to achieve is to create a datetime with todays date and then add days.
I also want it in ISO format with the UTC added.
The time should always be set to 12:00:00.0

So for example, if todays date is 2023-01-31 and my offset is 1, the end result should be:
2024-01-03T12:00:00Z

As I said, below works, but there must be a smarter way of doing it?

```
def setforecastdate(dateoffset):
    forecastdate = datetime.datetime.today()
    forecastdate += datetime.timedelta(days=int(dateoffset))
    forecastdate = forecastdate.replace(hour=12, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=0)
    forecastdate += datetime.timezone.utc.utcoffset(None)
    forecastdate = forecastdate.isoformat()
    forecastdate = str(forecastdate) + "Z"

    return forecastdate
```

Comment: When I run your code with offset 1, the result is 2024-01-01T12:00:00Z, not 2024-01-03T12:00:00Z

Comment: Should "today" be interpreted in the local timezone or in UTC? e.g. assume that your local time is CET, and you're running the program at 2024-01-01 00:30:00 CET, which is 2023-12-31 23:30:00 UTC. Is "today" 2024-01-01, or 2023-12-31?

Comment: @mzjn Sorry, wrote the wrong day, it should be 2024-01-01T12:00:00Z!

Comment: You should edit the question to eliminate confusion. Don't just explain the mistake in a comment.

Comment: @slothrop To be honest, I have not thought about it, but now that I am, it should always be UTC, but for simplicity it would be ok to do the easiest possible conversation.

Comment: The easy way to get today's date in UTC is `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: You taught me something new today.  Leading zeros aren't allowed on numeric literals, except apparently for `0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed. In Python 2 they were allowed, but indicated an octal literal, so for example `datetime.date(2024,07,01)` worked but `datetime.date(2024,08,01)` didn't.

Comment: @slothrop yes, I know the history.  I was talking about today's situation, nobody should be using Python 2 anymore.  Personally I think it was a mistake to make leading zeros a syntax error, even a child knows that leading zeros shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. I wonder though if the Py2 history played a role in the design decision. If you were creating a language from scratch, it would be sensible to make `020` behave the same as `20`. But if you did that in Py3, then `020` would be a valid literal in both versions, but with different values (20 in Py3, 16 in Py2). Maybe throwing a syntax error in Py3 was seen as a lesser evil compared to that.

Comment: @slothrop the creation of Py3 was intended to be a breaking point where wrongs could be righted.  I don't know from experience but assume that 2to3 automatically fixed those octal constants.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe you interpreted my comment as arguing in favour of the design decision? I wasn't, and don't personally have a strong opinion either way. Also, I think I misinterpreted you. Now I'm thinking that when you say "you taught me something new", you meant the fact that `00` is ok, and not the fact that `01` is not?

Comment: (You're right about 2to3 fixing the octal constants btw, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187248/python-2to3-tool-adds-a-vowel-to-my-integer)

Comment: @slothrop yes, I meant that I was surprised `00` was ok when I knew `01` was not.  Thanks for confirming 2to3 for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. As discussed in the comments, the starting point for the calculation should be "today" in UTC (better than in local time). So the process is:

1. Get the current datetime in UTC
2. Replace the time component of that with 12:00:00.0
3. Add a delta of `dateoffset` days
4. Convert to string and replace the `+00:00` timezone indicator with the `Z` that you want.

(Alternatively, steps 2 and 3 could be switched. The order of operations between them can make a difference in a timezone with daylight saving, but not in UTC.)

```
import datetime
from datetime import timezone

def setforecastdate(dateoffset):
    forecast_date = (datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
                     .replace(hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                     + datetime.timedelta(days=dateoffset))
    forecast_date_str = forecast_date.isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
    return forecast_date_str
```

Running today (2023-12-31), `setforecastdate(1)` gives `'2024-01-01T12:00:00Z'` as desired.

The whole function could be written in one line, but the way I've done it here puts the datetime manipulation in a separate line from the string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import datetime as dt

def setforecastdate(dateoffset):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    delt = dt.timedelta(days=dateoffset)
    fcdate = now+delt
    return fcdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT12:00:00Z')
```

Just being really lazy here and setting the hours:minutes:seconds as a string. You could also put the entire code in the function in one line but this is more readable.

If you want it in UTC you might have to replace `dt.datetime.now()` with `dt.datetime.utcnow()` .